# Why does dereferencing an undangling raw pointer returned from a function result in undefined behavior?

Tags: rust, unsafe, raw-pointer

I found dereferencing an undangling raw pointer will result in undefined behavior but I don't know why. I found that `Pin` solves my situation. Why is it not working?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ef7a9d8b178bc2f2d460c81440710e2)

```rust
fn main() {
    assert_not_eq(&Ref::pinned(1), &Ref::pinned(2));
    assert_not_eq(&Ref::raw(1), &Ref::raw(2)); // test failed
}

struct Ref<T> {
    value: T,
    reference: *const T,
}

use std::pin::Pin;
impl<T> Ref<T> {
    fn pinned(value: T) -> Pin<Box<Ref<T>>>
    where
        T: std::marker::Unpin,
    {
        let mut instance = Pin::new(Box::new(Self::dangling(value)));
        instance.reference = &mut instance.value;
        return instance;
    }

    fn raw(value: T) -> Ref<T> {
        let mut instance = Self::dangling(value);
        instance.reference = &mut instance.value;
        return instance;
    }

    fn dangling(value: T) -> Ref<T> {
        Ref {
            value,
            reference: 0 as *const T,
        }
    }
}

fn assert_not_eq<T: std::cmp::PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug + Copy>(first: &Ref<T>, second: &Ref<T>) {
    assert_eq!(unsafe { *first.reference }, first.value);
    assert_eq!(unsafe { *second.reference }, second.value);
    assert_ne!(first.value, second.value);
}
```

Comment: In `raw`, the `Ref` is allocated in that method's stack frame. `&mut instance.value` is therefore a pointer to somewhere on the stack. When `raw` returns, the `Ref` is copied from the method's stack frame into the caller's stack frame -- but `reference` isn't updated and still points to somewhere on the stack which is now invalid! That's bad.

Comment: `pinned` is different, as `Ref` is allocated on the heap. `&mut instance.value` therefore points to somewhere on the heap. This object doesn't move when `pinned` returns -- the pointer to the box is copied from the callee to caller, but the box it points to doesn't move, and so `instance.reference` stays valid

Comment: @canton7 You are right, the `&mut instance.value` expression in `raw` method will be dropped after evalulated, I forgot the stack & heap allocation. thanks very much.

Comment: Note that it isn't the `Pin` itself which is fixing the issue. Just heap-allocating with `Box` makes your code work. `Pin` is a guarantee that memory can't be moved -- without the `Pin`, the caller of `pinned` could move the `Ref` out of the box, and then you'd be in undefined terratory again. By returning a `Pin`, you ensure that the caller cannot move the `Ref` anywhere, and so its internal pointer stays valid

Comment: @canton7 Yes, I can fix the issus by change the return type of the `raw` method with `Box<Ref<T>>`, since `Ref` will allocated in heap. You reminded me, thanks.

Comment: Adding to what @canton7 said, `Pin` alone is not enough. You need to make `Ref: !Unpin`, which requires to add a field of type `std::marker::PhantomPinned`.

Comment: If you want to work with `Pin` and self-referential structs, make sure to read _very carefully_ the docs of [`std::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/). But it's _much_ preferred to avoid this, and `unsafe` in general, completely, at least until you know _exactly_ what you're doing.

Comment: Self-referential structs are especially dangerous because Miri cannot help you validate you don't have UB.